# how to cover trigger code in test class?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage

Writing test class for trigger i am getting code coverage.. Can any one help me how to cover test class..

Trigger:

```
trigger ConAllUpdate on Account (After update) {
       list<contact> cc = new list<contact>();
      list<contact> cc1 = new list<contact>();
      list<contact> con = new list<contact>();
      map<string,id> mapacc = new map<string,id>();
      for(account a:Trigger.new){  
        system.debug('Account'+a);
        mapacc.put(a.type,a.id);
        system.debug('Account:'+mapacc);
    }
    if(mapacc.containskey('sfdc')){
        cc = [select id,level__c from contact where accountid IN:mapacc.values()];
        system.debug('Contact:'+cc);
        if(cc.size()>0){
        for(contact c:cc){
        c.level__C = 'Primary';
        con.add(c);
    }
    }
    }
    else if(mapacc.containskey('dotcom')){
        cc1 = [select id,level__c from contact where accountid IN:mapacc.values()];
        system.debug('Contact:'+cc1);
        if(cc1.size()>0){
        for(contact co:cc1){
        co.level__C = 'Secondary';
        con.add(co);
    }
    }
    }
     if(con.size()>0){
        system.debug('Contact:'+con);
        update con;
    }
 }
```

Test Class:

```
@istest
public class Test_ConAllUpdate {
    Testmethod static void updatecon(){

        Account a = new account();
        a.name = 'test';
        a.type = 'sfdc';
        insert a;        
        contact c = new contact();
        c.lastname = 'testwelsome';
        c.level__C =  'primary';
        c.accountid= a.id;
        insert c;

        Account aa = new account();
        aa.name = 'test';
        aa.type = 'dotcom';
        insert aa;        
        contact cc = new contact();
        cc.lastname = 'testwelsome';
        cc.level__C =  'secondary';
        cc.accountid = aa.id;
        insert cc;
         }
}
```

Comment: please refer to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic, this is not a free coding service. If you have a specific problem in your code please point it out and reformulate your question with the specific problem, and expected output. thanks!

Comment: Thanks for responding.. i am not expecting full code already while asking question updated test class its not covering triggers want to know where i did mistake why i am not covering is there any issue in my test class for checking..

Comment: have you done the trailhead on unit testing? https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing/units/apex_testing_triggers

Comment: Say self, what type of trigger do I have "Ahh, an Update trigger". So now look at your test class, what is it missing, "Ahhh, an update". Also note even at that your test is not a test. It is a smoke test and does not validate that anything is actually happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was going to make this a comment, but as I continued writing it, it seemed like an answer was more appropriate.

Based on the text of your question, test classes (those with the `@istest` annotation) do not need to be covered. After continuing to look at your provided code, I don't think that's really what you're asking about though.

With your given test class, you should not be getting any coverage of the trigger you provided. Why do I say that? Because your trigger is on the `Account` object, and runs `after update`, and your unit test does not perform any update on any `Account`.

I'll also note that your current test class isn't really testing anything. It's good to remember that code coverage is merely a side-effect of unit testing (it's also the only metric that Salesforce can reasonably enforce for deployments). **The primary purpose of unit tests is to make sure that the output of your code matches your expectations, and you do that by making assertions** (using, for example, `system.assertEquals()`).

Generally speaking, each unit test (each individual `testMethod`) has 3 phases:

1. Set up the test data that is required for the test to run
2. Execute one specific method of the class that you're testing
3. Grab the updated data (sometimes you need to query for it, other times you can use the data returned from a method), and make assertions against the ending state of your data

Right now, your unit test is performing the first step only. When I write unit tests, I go through a mental checklist (each step neatly corresponds to one of the phases of testing I described before):

- What method/trigger am I testing? (Phase 1)
- Going one level deeper, are there any if/else blocks or for loops? If so, which *one* of them do I want to execute in this particular test? (Phase 1)
- What data do I need to have in place to guarantee that I will execute the specific portion of code that I want to test? (Phase 1)
- What is my entry point (where do I need to start the test execution to run the code that I want to test)? (Phase 2)
- What are the results that I am expecting (i.e. this record should be deleted, that record should have a specific value in fields x and y, etc...)? (Phase 3)

If I were to go through this checklist with your trigger, this is what I'd come up with:

- I'm testing an `after update` trigger on `Account`
- With one test, I want to test the code in the `if(map.containsKey('sfdc'))` block
- I will need to insert at least one `Account`, and at least one `Contact`
- To reach this if block, I will need to cause the trigger (the one being tested) to run. Since it is on `Account`, and runs `after update`, I will need to `update myAccount;` to cause my code to be executed
- After my code runs, I expect the `level__c` of the test `Contact` related to my test `Account` to hold the value 'Primary'

Once you have that, you pretty much have everything you need to write an effective, useful unit test. Translating that into actual test code would end up looking like this:

```
@isTest
private class myUnitTest{
    // I like to give my test methods descriptive names.
    // That way, if the test fails, I immediately have some idea of what isn't working,
    //   and can possibly start to narrow down where the problematic code is
    private testMethod void testAccountTypeSFDCMakesContactPrimary(){
        // Phase 1: setup the test environment
        // I need at least one account, and at least one contact related to that account

        // Using the sObject constructor like this is one way to initialize an SObject
        //   with data.
        Account testAcc = new Account(
            Name = 'test',
            Type__c = 'sfdc'
        );

        insert testAcc;

        // Take note that we don't want to set level__c here.
        // We want the test to do this so we can later verify that the code
        //   being tested performed as expected.
        Contact testCont = new Contact(
            lastName = 'McPerson',
            AccountId = testAcc.Id
        );

        insert testCont;

        // In some situations, it can be a good idea to verify the state of your target
        //   data before actually executing the test.
        // Doing this here, in this case, will ensure that the act of inserting the test
        //   Contact didn't change any data that we'll try to verify later.
        testCont = [SELECT Id, level__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :testCont.Id];

        // assertEquals() and assertNotEquals() can take either 2 or 3 parameters.
        // The first parameter is the value that you expect, the second parameter is 
        //   the value you actually have, and the third is the message to print
        //   when the assertion fails.
        // Having a specific failure message is helpful, aim to make the message
        //   contain details about what failed, and why.
        // Doing so can give you hints as to what went wrong (and what code might need
        //   to be fixed) long after you've forgotten exactly what the test (or the code 
        //   being tested) does.
        System.assertNotEquals('Primary', testCont.level__c, 'testContact\'s level__c was set to primary before executing the test');

        // Phase 2, executing the test
        // To get the code we're trying to test to run, we need to update the test Account.
        // Test.startTest()/Test.stopTest() aren't strictly required, but it's a good
        //   habit to get into.
        Test.startTest();
        update testAcc;
        Test.stopTest();

        // Phase 3, verify results
        // Since the trigger we're testing updates Contacts, we will need to query
        //   for our test contact to get the data that was updated by the trigger.
        testCont = [SELECT Id, level__c FROM Contact WHERE Id = :testCont.Id];

        System.assertEquals('Primary', testCont.level__c, 'Account after update trigger did not change level__c to the expected value');
    }
}
```

I hope that provides enough insight for you. In practice, I generally have separate test methods if I need to test a group of if/else statements. I'd highly recommend making a separate test to verify that a `Contact` can be updated to hold 'Secondary' in its `level__c` field, and I'll leave that one up to you.

Answer (score 2):

As far as coverage goes, you can simply add this line at the end of your test method:

```
update new List<Account> { a, aa };
```

However, coverage is *not* the primary purpose of unit tests, but merely an enforcement mechanism. Rather, the end goal is to ***verify application behavior***. You do so by adding assertions. In this case you would re-query for the `Contact` records and assert they were properly updated.

I recommend you read **[How to Write Good Unit Tests](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests)** in its entirety, but this stretch is particularly relevant:

> #### [Verify the results are correct](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/How_to_Write_Good_Unit_Tests#Verify_the_results_are_correct)
>
> Verifying that your code works as you expect it to work is the most important part of unit testing. It’s also one of the things that Force.com developers commonly neglect. Unit tests that do not verify the results of the code aren’t true unit tests. They are commonly referred to as smoke tests, which aren’t nearly as effective or informative as true unit tests.
>
> A good way to tell if unit tests are properly verifying results is to look for liberal use of the `System.assert()` methods. If there aren’t any `System.assert()` method calls, then the tests aren’t verifying results properly. And, no, `System.assert(true);` doesn’t count.

Another point here is that *unit* tests should verify exactly one aspect of platform behavior. As such, you really are testing too much in one go. You should have one test where you insert and update an `Account` whose `Type` is equal to `'sfdc'`, and then an entirely separate test where you test a record whose `Type` is `'dotcom'`. You really should have at least one more – a bulk test where you update 200 records to make sure your trigger is bulk-safe.

To that end, another thing you are missing are your calls to `Test.startTest()` and `Test.stopTest()`. These help you accurately test governor limits, and also ensure asynchronous operations are complete, though that is not necessarily a concern here.